# How check if type is class?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core

In .Net we have `Type.IsClass` to check if a type is a class using `System.Reflection`.

But in *.Net Core* no. So, how can I check?

Comment: Always I use google before, if you think this question is useful please give a negative vote, but not make useless comments.

Comment: @MethodMan 100% disagree considering the subset of API in .net core 1.x

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try calling `GetTypeInfo()` to get at this information.

Answer (score 11):

This is ok, on: **.net Core 1.1**

```
using System.Reflection;
bool isClass = obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsClass;
```

Answer (score 10):

In **.NET Core 2.2** you can do:

```
bool isClass = obj.GetType().IsClass;
```

The following will no longer work:

```
bool isClass = obj.GetTypeInfo().IsClass;
bool isClass = obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsClass;
```